# Multiple plots in same figure in for loop

Tags: matlab, loops, plot, figure

i am sorry as this seems a stereotypically common question, however, even when taking care of 'hold on', I cant figure what I am doing wrng here. My plots are getting overwritten by each other. I would like to get multiple plots for the innermost loop in the same figure. Kindly suggest.

```
userName={'A' 'B' 'C'  'Z' 'R'};
timeCategories={'All' 'Morning' 'Afternoon' 'Evening'};
for user=1:5
    currentUserName= char(userName(user));    
    for K=1:4
        method='Al';
        fig=figure();
        xlabel('Recall', 'FontSize',12,'FontWeight','bold');
        ylabel('Precision','FontSize',12, 'FontWeight','bold');
       titleOfFig=strcat('PrecisionRecall\_',currentUserName,'\_','Top',num2str(K));
        title(titleOfFig,'FontSize',17,'FontWeight','bold'); 
        set(gca,'XColor',[.0 .3 .2],'YColor',[.0 .3 .2],'LineWidth',2, 'FontSize',11, 'FontWeight','bold');
        axis([0 1 0 1]);
        grid on;
        filename = sprintf('%sPrecisionRecall_%s_Top%d.png',path,currentUserName,K); %path,'PrecisionRecall\_',userName(1),'\_','Top',num2str(K),'.png');
        hold on;
        for timeCat=1:4
            timeCategory=char(timeCategories(timeCat));
            precisionFileName=strcat(method,timeCategory,'top',num2str(K),...
            'Precision.csv');
            recallFileName=strcat(method,timeCategory,'top',num2str(K),'Recall.csv');
            Ptemp= csvread(precisionFileName);
            Rtemp= csvread(recallFileName);
            precisionVector=Ptemp(user,:);
            recallVector=Rtemp(user,:);
            h= plot(recallVector,precisionVector,'r--*','MarkerSize',8);
            hold on;
            set(h,'LineWidth',2);
        end
        legend(timeCategories,'Location','Best');
        print(fig, '-dpng',filename,'-r200');
     end 
end
```

Comment: This might not be considered as an answer but have you tried to use `hold all`?

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding what you mean by your *plots are getting overwritten by each other*? What exactly is happening?

Comment: I guess your plot is not getting replaced, you are getting the same plot again and again. Please see your code. In the inner most loop, replace `precisionVector=ptemp(1,:)` with `precisionVector=ptemp(timeCat,:)` and in the same way `recallVector=Rtemp(1,:)` with `recallVector=Rtemp(timeCat,:)`. Then you will get it correct.

Comment: @Naveen - Nice catch.  That should solve it

Comment: @Naveen he is already defining a new csv dependent on `K` and `timeCat`. Are the values in the csv different?

Comment: @Naveen @ironzionlion yes...the csv file read are different for different `timeCat`. @Croco `hold all` is not making any differece.

Comment: csv file read is not different for different timeCat. You should replace K by timeCat.

Comment: thanks @EJG89, but different `timeCat` --> different `timeCategory` --> different csv files to be read --> different Ptemp and Rtemp in each iteration

Comment: Million thanks everyone for your help and time, the problem was: even though the vectors to plot were different in each iteration, the values were either of two values, so the points were plotted exactly on top of each other. I found it by changing to scatter plot with jitter.

Answer (score 0):

Like Naveen pointed out you didn't use your loop index ;) Please note that you only have to set hold on once per figure. So the hold on within your timeCat loop is unnecessary. Hold on holds until you open a new figure or when you call a hold off.

Added generic data to show that the code below is working properly. The problem must be in your data since your data is not dependent on timeCat.

@ironzionlion
Yes, indeed the variables P are assigned every for loop but the variable is the same during the loop. Therefore I assumed he forgot to use the variable timeCat to identify the correct row. However, you might call the wrong file. The rest of his code is working fine, as you can see in my code using generic data.

Please check what data you are reading from the CSV file and see how you can access this data.

Kind regards,

Ernst Jan

```
close all
clear all

userName={'A' 'B' 'C'  'Z' 'R'};
timeCategories={'All' 'Morning' 'Afternoon' 'Evening'};
for user=1:5
    currentUserName= char(userName(user));    
    for K=1:4
        method='Al';
        fig=figure();
        xlabel('Recall', 'FontSize',12,'FontWeight','bold');
        ylabel('Precision','FontSize',12, 'FontWeight','bold');
        titleOfFig=strcat('PrecisionRecall\_',currentUserName,'\_','Top',num2str(K));
        title(titleOfFig,'FontSize',17,'FontWeight','bold'); 
        set(gca,'XColor',[.0 .3 .2],'YColor',[.0 .3 .2],'LineWidth',2, 'FontSize',11, 'FontWeight','bold');
%         axis([0 1 0 1]);
        grid on;
        %filename = sprintf('%sPrecisionRecall_%s_Top%d.png',path,currentUserName,K); %path,'PrecisionRecall\_',userName(1),'\_','Top',num2str(K),'.png');
        hold on;
        for timeCat=1:4
            timeCategory=char(timeCategories(timeCat));
            precisionFileName=strcat(method,timeCategory,'top',num2str(K),...
            'Precision.csv');
            recallFileName=strcat(method,timeCategory,'top',num2str(K),'Recall.csv');
            Ptemp= timeCat.*[1:10];
            Rtemp= (1:10)/10;
            %precisionVector=Ptemp(1,:); % Call with loop variable!
            precisionVector=Ptemp;
            %recallVector=Rtemp(1,:); % Call with loop variable!
            recallVector=Rtemp;
            h= plot(recallVector,precisionVector,'r--*','MarkerSize',8);
            % hold on; You don't need this one I think.
            set(h,'LineWidth',2);
        end
        legend(timeCategories,'Location','Best');
        filename = [num2str(K),num2str(user)];
        print(fig, '-dpng',filename,'-r200');
     end 
end
```

Comment: thanks , however, `Ptemp` and `Rtemp` are already dependent on the loop variable as the csv file to be read are dependent on loop variable.

Comment: I am wondering who down-voted a working solution. Anyway, the code as provided in the answer (using generic data) plots four lines for each figure (20 in total). Thus is working properly. Please edit the above code step by step so you can identify where your problem is.